# Why am I not getting any output in the below code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

There are no errors while compiling the code. I am calling the function as: `pattern('abc')`. Expecting output as `'A-Bb-Ccc'`

```
def pattern(s):
    v = []
    v = list(s)
    strlen = len(v)
    i = 0
    cntr = 0
    strng = []
    while i < strlen:
        j = 0
        while j <= i:
            if j == 0:
                strng.append(v[i].upper())
            else:
                strng.append(v[i])
        j += 1
        strng.append('-')
        i += 1
        z = ''.join(strng)
        return z
```

Comment: How do you know if the output is not correct if you are not printing it?

Comment: Well the indent on 'return z' is wrong, tab back once

Comment: Are you printing `z` after return? `print pattern('abc')` ??

Comment: As it is, it's impossible for this function to output _nothing_. At minimum, it will return a dash `-`.

Comment: This enters an infinite loop. I think you need an additional indent on `j += 1`

Comment: `j` is incremented outside the loop. So the loop will possibly run infinitely.

Comment: The function is returning string z. Shouldn't that get printed automatically?

Comment: additional indent on  j += 1 worked. Thanks !

Comment: @Kshitij nothing will be printed automatically, you have to explicitly print the value. But are you sure this works? If I call with `pattern('abc')` with the corrected indentation of `j += 1` I get `'A-'` which is not your expected output.

Comment: @roganjosh the return statement is not correctly incremented either =/ It should be 4 spaces to the left (outside the outer while loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**  using `enumerate` instead of `zip`

```
source = 'abc'

'-'.join([(x*i).capitalize() for i, x in  enumerate(source, 1)])
```

---

```
source = 'abc'

'-'.join([(x*i).capitalize() for x,i in  zip(source, range(1, len(source)+1))])
```

Some explanations:

`zip(source, range(1, len(source)+1))`  create pairs `(a,1), (b,2), (c,3)`

`x*i` means concatenation i.e. `a*3` generate the string `aaa`

`aaa.capitalize()` makes first letter a capital one

`'-'.join(a_list)` joins elements in `a_list` using `-` as separator

Comment: While this is a nice pice of code, it does not Answer the question: "Why am I not getting any output in the below code?". You may want to edit something in that answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

You have no print statement. To test it, fill in

`print(z)`.

Also you have to put the return outside of the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Well first, you need to indent `return z` so it is not in any of the loops:

```
def pattern(s):
    #Rest of the code
    return z
```

Then you need to assign the result of the function to a variable and print it:

```
result = pattern('abc')
print result
```

Or you could do a more direct method:

```
print pattern('abc')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop. You need to have `j` increment in the inner `while` loop or `j` will always be less then `i` if you call `print(pattern("abc"))` after you fix the indentation it should return what you are looking for.

TL;DR, add an indent before `j+=1`